# Como colocar between dentro de uma consulta em código?

Tags: c#, sql, .net, string, ado.net

Tenho a seguinte consulta e gostaria de colocar na cláusula `Where` a condição de estar dentro de um determinado período.

```
public static DataTable stCloseCaseAll(int schoolId, string dataInicial, string datafinal)
{
    var sb = new StringBuilder();

    sb.Append(" SELECT C.SchoolID, C.DateClose, C.UserAdminID, C.CloseCaseID, C.Balance, C.PCName, U.Name ");
    sb.Append(" FROM  sales.CloseCase AS C INNER JOIN ");
    sb.Append(" [authorization].UserAdmin AS U ON C.UserAdminID = U.UserAdminID ");
    sb.Append(" WHERE  (C.SchoolID = " + schoolId + ") AND ... ");

    return AcessoDados.SelectDados(sb.ToString(), "conexao");
}
```

Estou obtendo as datas para a consulta através de um *textbox*.

```
namespace IASD.ASCS.WebForm.reports.closemonth.Report
{
    public partial class Default : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ReportDocument crReportDocument = new ReportDocument();
            dsClosemonth dsRelatorio = new dsClosemonth();

            int schoolId = 0;
            string dataInicial = null;
            string dataFinal = null;
            string schoolName = "";

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Request.QueryString[0]))
            {
                schoolId = int.Parse(Request.QueryString[0]);
            }

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Request.QueryString[1]))
            {
                schoolName = Request.QueryString[1];
            }

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Request.QueryString[2]))
            {
                dataInicial = Request.QueryString[2];
            }

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Request.QueryString[3]))
            {
                dataFinal = Request.QueryString[3];
            }

            dsRelatorio.CloseCase.Merge(Bussiness.CloseCase.stCloseCaseAll(schoolId, dataInicial, dataFinal));

            IB.Schools obj = IB.Schools.ListSchoolName(schoolId);

            crReportDocument.Load(Server.MapPath("crClosemonth.rpt"));
            crReportDocument.SetDataSource(dsRelatorio);
            crReportDocument.SetParameterValue("SchoolId", schoolId);
            crReportDocument.SetParameterValue("SchoolName",schoolName);
            crReportDocument.SetParameterValue("DataInicial", dataInicial);
            crReportDocument.SetParameterValue("DataFinal", dataFinal);

            //Utilizando exportação para pdf
            BinaryReader stream = new BinaryReader(crReportDocument.ExportToStream(CrystalDecisions.Shared.ExportFormatType.PortableDocFormat));

            HttpContext.Current.Response.ClearContent();
            HttpContext.Current.Response.ClearHeaders();
            HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
            HttpContext.Current.Response.BinaryWrite(stream.ReadBytes(Convert.ToInt32(stream.BaseStream.Length)));
            HttpContext.Current.Response.Flush();
            HttpContext.Current.Response.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

***NavigateURL:***

```
protected void LoadNavigateUrl()
{
    if ((!string.IsNullOrEmpty(ddlSchool.SelectedValue) && (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtDateInitial.Text)) &&
         (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(txtDateEnd.Text))))
    {
        hlPrint.Enabled = true;
        hlPrint.Visible = true;
        hlPrint.NavigateUrl = "/reports/closemonth/report/?SchoolID="+ddlSchool.SelectedValue+"&SchoolName="+ddlSchool.SelectedItem+"&InitialDate="+txtDateInitial.Text+"&EndDate="+txtDateEnd.Text;
    }
}
```

Tentei dessa forma mas não funcionou

```
public static DataTable stCloseCaseAll(int schoolId, string dataInicial, string datafinal)
{
    var sb = new StringBuilder();

    var @dataInincial = dataInicial;
    var @datafnal = datafinal;

    sb.Append(" SELECT C.SchoolID, C.DateClose, C.UserAdminID, C.CloseCaseID, C.Balance, C.PCName, U.Name ");
    sb.Append(" FROM  sales.CloseCase AS C INNER JOIN ");
    sb.Append(" [authorization].UserAdmin AS U ON C.UserAdminID = U.UserAdminID ");
    sb.Append(" WHERE  (C.SchoolID = " + schoolId + ") AND (DAY(C.DateClose) between @dataInicial and @datafinal )" );

    return AcessoDados.SelectDados(sb.ToString(), "conexao");
}
```

Comment: AND... c.DateClose between 01/01/01 and 31/12/01?

Comment: Isso, só que como eu passo a data recebida do txtDateInitial.Text e txtDateEnd.Text?

Comment: Fiz um update na pergunta para ficar mais fácil de entender.

Comment: Sei que a pergunta é cretina, mas já tentou passar as variáveis da mesma forma que passou o `schoolId? ` `"(C.SchoolID = " + schoolId + ") AND (C.DateClose between " + @dataInicial + " and " + @datafinal + ")"`

Comment: ok? se você resolveu o problema, pode colocar a solução como uma resposta sem problemas. Não precisa editar a pergunta. Do jeito que está, parece que a pergunta está ainda em aberto.

Comment: Esta abordagem não é boa. Não há parametrização dos dados, então o SQL pode ficar frágil, propenso a *injections*.

Comment: Secundando o comentário do @Cigano, estás a pedir para o teu site ser atacado! Nunca uses concatenação de strings para construir comandos SQL. O número de alocações de memória (e consequente garbage collections) da aplicação web vai aumentar, o SQL Server não consegue otimizar o comando e está mesmo a pedir SQL Injection. Usa sempre SqlParameter nos teus SqlSommand.

Answer (score 1):

Cigano está certo, esta abordagem não é correta pela possibilidade de SQL injection, mesmo que esteja funcionando.
sugiro que leia este artigo da MSDN:
[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yy6y35y8(v=vs.110).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yy6y35y8%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Utilize o método `command.Parameters.Add`, ele facilitará sua vida com diversos tipos de dados nos parâmetros.

Answer (score 1):

Solução ( O problema estava em converter as datas ).

```
sb.Append(" SELECT C.SchoolID, C.DateClose, C.UserAdminID, C.CloseCaseID, C.Balance, C.PCName, U.Name ");
sb.Append(" FROM  sales.CloseCase AS C INNER JOIN ");
sb.Append(" [authorization].UserAdmin AS U ON C.UserAdminID = U.UserAdminID ");
sb.Append(" WHERE  C.SchoolID = " + schoolId);
sb.Append(" AND C.DateClose BETWEEN " + "CONVERT(DATETIME ,'" +    DateTime.Parse(dataInicial).ToString("yyyy/MM/dd") + "') AND " + "CONVERT(DATETIME ,'" + DateTime.Parse(datafinal).ToString("yyyy/MM/dd") + " 23:59:59')");
```

<sup>Apenas coloquei a solução do OP como resposta. mas é bom ouvir as recomendados dadas em comentários e na outra resposta.</sup>